# How pass args to wp_list_comments callback?

Tags: oop, comments

i need to pass an arg to function that i am specifying as callback for `wp_list_comments`

```
public function ggowl_comment_lister($ggowl_id,$icon_html){
        $args = array (
         'post_type' => 'product',
         'post_id' => $ggowl_id
        );
        $comments = get_comments( $args );
        $args = array(
          'callback' => array($this, 'ggowl_woocommerce_comments'),
        );
        wp_list_comments( $args , $comments);
      }
```

but `public function ggowl_woocommerce_comments($ggowl_id){` this does not work as `$ggowl_id` is not defined

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the `wp_list_comments()` and `Walker_Comment` sources I would assume the callback is what the Walker uses to render single comments. And the callback recieves three parameters `$comment, $args, $depth` when the Walker calls it.

Based on this, I assume you should be able to just push custom key-value pairs to your `$args` array and then have them available when the callback function is called.

This is slighty unfamiliar territory for me, so I may be mistaken.